# Divide a query result having multiple records with another query result having multiple records in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two queries giving two sets of result, i want to divide one query's result with another.

Here is my first query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM survey_event_answers a JOIN survey_events e ON a.eventid = e.eventid
WHERE e.event_status = 'Closed' AND 
      e.survey_date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2014-01-31' AND 
      a.response_options IN (10,11) AND a.questionid = 7 
GROUP BY MONTH(e.survey_date) DESC;
```

Here is the result of this query :

```
279
443
664
743
785
1312
1085
915
231
```

Here is my another query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*),e.survey_date 
FROM `survey_event_answers` a INNER JOIN survey_events e ON a.eventid = e.eventid
WHERE e.event_status='Closed' AND 
      e.survey_date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2014-01-31' AND 
      a.questionid=7 
GROUP BY MONTH(e.survey_date) DESC
```

Here is the query result :

```
351
539
826
926
984
1654
1378
1165
844
```

I want that first row of first result set should divide by first row of second row set.

Please help me out how can i do this.

Thanks

Comment: You realise that the first result is January, right?

Comment: yes they are group by months.

Comment: Since you have no `ORDER BY`, the rows may be in pseudo random order ([at least in newer versions of MySQL](http://www.tocker.ca/2013/10/21/heads-up-implicit-sorting-by-group-by-is-deprecated-in-mysql-5-6.html)).

Comment: `GROUP BY … DESC` is illegal.

Comment: @VigneshKumar I have no idea what you're talking about. However, your markup is less readable than mine.

Comment: The second query should have two columns of results.

Comment: @Alex GROUP BY DESC is not illegal

Answer (score 0):

is this what are you looking for?

```
SELECT rd1.r1/rd2.r2 `result`
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) r1,MONTH(e.survey_date) d1
    FROM `survey_event_answers` a 
    INNER JOIN survey_events e 
    ON (a.eventid = e.eventid) 
    WHERE e.event_status='Closed' AND e.survey_date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2014-01-31'
    AND a.response_options IN (10,11) AND a.questionid=7 
    GROUP BY MONTH(e.survey_date) DESC ) rd1
 JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) r2, MONTH(e.survey_date) d2 
    FROM `survey_event_answers` a 
    INNER JOIN survey_events e 
    ON (a.eventid = e.eventid) 
    WHERE e.event_status='Closed' AND e.survey_date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2014-01-31'
    AND a.questionid=7 
    GROUP BY MONTH(e.survey_date) DESC ) rd2
  ON rd1.d1=rd2.d2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
  SELECT SUM(IF(a.response_options IN (10,11), 1, 0))/COUNT(*) 
    FROM survey_event_answers a 
    JOIN survey_events e 
      ON a.eventid = e.eventid
   WHERE e.event_status = 'Closed' 
     AND e.survey_date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2014-01-31' 
     AND a.questionid = 7 
 GROUP BY MONTH(e.survey_date) DESC;
```

This may not be fast (but it is faster than doing the query twice and joining the results), but probably do what you want (ratio of answers 10 or 11). You can add the `MONTH(e.survey_date)` as a second column.